# Spring boot getting 401 unauthorized status code for simple get request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am very new to Spring framework. I have created a new Spring Starter Project with following modules: web, mongo, security.

I have created a simple controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        List<User> users = this.userRepository.findAll();
        return users;
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public void insert(@RequestBody User user){
        this.userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

And seeded some raw data to the database. When I make request to this route in Postman, I get the following response:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1511113712858,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
    "path": "/users/all"
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ngt</groupId>
<artifactId>someArtifact</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>dermaskin</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot with mongodb</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What is causing the unauthorized response and how to disable it for the `/all` route? Thanks!

Comment: Ok now remove or comment the  spring-boot-starter-security from your pom file. and try again.

Comment: but in the case I will need it for certain routes? For eg for logging in and registering I don't need it, but for other remaining routes I need it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/users/all").permitAll();
    }
}
```

You need to configure Spring Security, by default all routes all secured for authrorization.

The code above disables security only for "/users/all" URL.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error as I included

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in my pom.xml file.
Just remove it and try again.

Comment: This is not an answer. You should add a comment if you're getting an error while trying to help.

Comment: @thehandofNOD - are you sure?

Comment: @WaiHaLee: Pretty much. How does this post answer the question? In the question the author did not even include the `oauth2-client` dependency. Also the other answers provided information.

Comment: @thehandofNOD - well, in any event it look *slightly* less like a "I'm having this problem too" answer now. I think it is an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: But I read it like: "I added the dependency `...oauth2-client` got an error, so just remove it and try again. It works. Does not sound like a solution to solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your security dependency but then you have to setup a userid and a password. This can be done by adding the following into your application.properties file located under
**src/main/resources**
folder

```
security.user.name=user # Default user name.
security.user.password= # your password here
```

Comment: sts shows me that `spring.security.enabled=false` is an unkown property

Comment: It's just a warning and shouldnt prevent it from working . Do you still have the 401 error ?

Comment: @AchillesVan I followed ur advice and created an application.properties inside resources in the module and added the text u mentioned, I'm still getting 401 on all APIs '< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"' any more suggestions?